# What is this metal utensil tool with wooden handle?

Tags: utensils

Saw this at a flea market with other kitchen tools and do not know what it is. The end of the tool that is pictured is attached to a wooden handle, not a gear or some other mechanical attachment.[image: end of tool]

**Update**: I'm still Google searching periodically. Other ideas include parts for a cookie/pasta press.

This is what the handle looks like:
[image: Grill Scraper]
<sub>(source: [bullbbq.com](https://www.bullbbq.com/sites/default/files/styles/product_large/public/product/grill-care/24142.jpg?itok=ZQ_hDHAX))</sub>

I think I'm on a lead with these grill scrapers.

Comment: I'd love to see the whole thing. The single angle leaves a few details out. Is there anything on the other side of the "blade"? Any grooves, humps, pockets or little raised hooks? Is this blade flat, convex, or slightly concave? Is the "typical" whisk handle wooden, wire coil, or solid shaft? Does it have any engage points where it might be inserted into something or paired with another utensil? I have two gadgets that might be related to this, one for whipping cream and one for making butter, but neither seems to be exactly like that one and both have more details than are seen in your photo.

Comment: The disk is in one 2D plane. I don't think it meant to mix anything. The complete lack of symmetry make me think that it is done sort of "selector", maybe fit some sort of extrusion(pasta?). the handle was wooden like it was meant to be held. I'm wondering now if it isn't for the kitchen at all.

Comment: Odd utensil/tool. The 2D thing doesn't make sense for food prep, but your "selector" theory sounds good. On the other hand, a selector that has a wooden handle and isn't connected to whatever is being selected is kind of strange, too. I hope you don't mind, but I am going to print out this photo and see if my neighbor has ever seen something like this. So far, he has ID every other odd contraption I've brought him.

Comment: You should post an answer of grill scraper - I think that's actually the one that makes sense, though it's in a format that suggests other uses, but then the tool does not make sense for various reasons in the other uses. For a grill scraper, it all makes sense...note that answering your own question is perfectly fine on Stack Exchange (though it votes better when not contrived as some folks like to do.)

Comment: That yellowish, iridescent finish looks like it could be cadmium plated - not something you want near food or heat.

Comment: Just because is was at a flea market with kitchen tools does not mean it is a kitchen tool.

Comment: In what universe is that handle type typical for whisks? Just wondering...

Comment: @Marti, agreed, that wasn't a good way to describe what I meant. Since I meant to convey that it was handled that is now what I actually say.

Comment: You really need to take that thing off the handle and make a necklace pendant out of it.  Or better: a string tie!

Answer (score 5):

I'm fairly confident that the tool is in fact a grill scraper. The handle matches the wooden one shown below. I can't think of any other explanation for the one indent on the tool that is like a hook. You ban see it matches the one in the two metal scrapers. The idea behind the design is to scrape both sides of the grill rung at the same time. 
[image: Grill Scraper]
[image: another grill scraper]
[image: pocket grill scraper]

Answer (score -1):

I am sure it is a blade of some sort that is attached to a machine that makes it turn. Since it is made of wood it could be that it is a hand held device.

Comment: theonlymo, welcome to Seasoned Advice! I see you have posted quite a few answers already. I'd like to encourage you to take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about this site and the Stack Exchange system.

Comment: I don't think it is a blade. It is not sharp at all. Also, the asymmetrical nature is a contraindication for a blade.

Comment: Zak, don't discount "blade" too early. It looks quite a bit like an emulsification blade as used in some blenders for making mayonnaise (and probably has been used by manual mayonnaise beaters before blenders became commonplace). The asymmetry is indeed a point against it, but people create unusual tools sometimes.